# Evaluating controller property everytime the template is rendered in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a template called sample and I am changing the property show in the controller based on a button press. Now I want the controller to reset the property every time the template is rendered. Currently even if I go to 'next' template and come back, the property show remains true if the button on sample was pressed. I want to change this behaviour and the property show should be false by default. I know I can do this by defining a view and using the didInsertElement hook but is that the only way to do this?? Ember.js website says that Views in Ember.js are typically only created for the following reasons:

When you need sophisticated handling of user events
When you want to create a re-usable component

and I am doing none of the above. Here is some sample code:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sample">
        {{#if show}}
            Showing stuff
        {{/if}}
        <button {{action changeShow}}>Change</button>
        {{#link-to 'next'}} Next {{/link-to}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="next">
        Hello
        {{#link-to 'sample'}}Back{{/link-to}}
</script>
App.SampleController=Ember.Controllers.Extend{(
    show:false,
    actions:{
        changeShow:function(){
            this.controllerFor('sample').set('show',true);
        }
    }
)};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the renderTemplate hook for the route you're doing this in, and change the controller variable in there.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate

I'd do something like this:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    var favController = this.controllerFor('favoritePost');
    favController.set("toggle", false)
    this._super()
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This works for me. I also tried using the afterRender hook to do something once the template is loaded but it didn't work. Is there any other hook which I can use to do things after the template has been rendered?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `didTransition` action which will trigger automatically once the transition happened. [didTransition action](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_didTransition)

```
App.SampleController=Ember.Controllers.Extend{(
    show:false,
    actions:{
        didTransition:function(){
             this.controllerFor('sample').set('show',false);  
        },
        changeShow:function(){
            this.controllerFor('sample').set('show',true);
        }
    }
)};
```